# Taskbar on secondary monitor in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I am looking for a free virtual-desktop program that will allow me to put a different virtual desktop on each of my two monitors (one on laptop and the other external)

How I would like to use it: I do a lot of work connecting to other servers using remote desktop. I would like to use the external monitor to open remote desktop in full screen and use the laptop monitor for the local machine to view my mails, chat, browser, etc.

I am using XP SP3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MultiMonitor TaskBar](http://www.mediachance.com/free/multimon.htm) creates a secondary taskbar on the extended monitors.

You can download it from [here](http://www.mediachance.com/free/mmtaskbar21.exe).

Comment: MultiMonitor TaskBar is good and useful, but individual desktop on each machine would be really nice. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible with the built-in multi-monitor from XP?

If the two monitors are recognized as two desktops (depends what you use for that), then you can maximize a window in one of them (typically, the remote desktop one) without problem.

Or maybe I'm missing something, feel free to point this for me.

Comment: With the plain old multiple monitors set up I can get the taskbar only on the primary monitor. So if I have multiple desktops on the external monitor (one for each remote machine) I can see the windows on latop from only one of these desktops.

Comment: Ok, I thought taskbar wouldn't be an issue because you would have one maximized window per monitor only. Your problem is indeed a bigger one, met by most of people with multimonitor, the case of the unique taskbar. Maybe rework your question to point more that this is your main issue.

Comment: can't you use the taskbar to switch the windows located on the other screen, even if it's on the main screen? For each remote desktop, you'll have a taskbar button.